# What is syntactically wrong with this Ruby case statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, case

For some reason, the `when @orgs` is not working :

```
  @orgs = Organization.all.select{|a|a.active}.count
  case collection.size
  when 0; "No #{entry_name.pluralize} found"
  when @orgs; "#{@orgs} Businesses Returned!"
  else; "#{collection.total_entries} of #{@orgs} Businesses Returned!"
  end
```

Is this syntactically accurate? It will always return the last `else` statement. It never catches on the second when statement, even if @orgs == @orgs.

The actual number of @orgs = 1211.

So if I make the when statement `when 1211;` , it still doesn't catch. Is there a syntactical mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax isn't the issue. The logic in your conditions, I think, is all messed up.

So, @orgs **does not = 1211**, @orgs is a collection whose size is 1211. Big difference.

- This case statement will always fail because the case is `collection.size`, when it should probably be `@orgs.size`

Let's say we changed it to be:

```
case @orgs.size
  ...
```

Then:

- Your first `when` statement would start working when `@orgs.size == 0`
- Your second `when` statement would still fail, because `@orgs.size != @orgs` - and it never will. `@orgs` refers to the collection of objects, while `@orgs.size` refers to the size of that collection. Even when `@orgs == nil` it will still fail because `@orgs.size` will throw a error because you're calling the `size` method on a `nil` object, which isn't allowed.
- Your `else` statement is **always** the one called because of the problems listed above, and because the way you've written it prevent any of the other cases from ever being true.

However, that's probably still not enough. It looks to me like you're trying to return singularized or pluralized text depending on how many you have. Here's the code you probably intended to write, without the semi-colon usage:

```
@active_orgs = Organization.all.select{|a| a.active}
@singular_name = Organization.class.name
@plural_name = @singular_form.pluralize

case @active_orgs.size
when 1
  "1 active #{@singular_name} of a total #{Organization.count} #{@plural_name}!"
else
  "#{@active_orgs.count} active #{@singular_name} of a total #{Organization.count} #{@plural_name}!"
end
```

This will pluralize even when the count is `0`, so it will say `0 active Organizations of a total 125 Organizations!`

... or when the value is `1` it will say `1 active Organization of a total 125 Organziations!`

If you don't want `Organization` capitalized, you can add a call to `.downcase` to take care of that.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right: `@orgs` starts as an array (through `all`, then `select`), then becomes an `int` with the call to `count` (which Array mixes in via `Enumerable`). So the matching shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Ok, but what's `collection.size` and `entry_name`? This is either incorrect, or there's code in this method not being shown.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that code isn't being shown. Otherwise, `size` would be called on `nil`, raising an error.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the following syntax ?

```
case collection.size
  when 0 then "No #{entry_name.pluralize} found"
  when @orgs then "#{@orgs} Businesses Returned!"
  else "#{collection.total_entries} of #{@orgs} Businesses Returned!"
  end
```